# Two containers on the same line, but the second one takes the space of 2 starting from the 2nd line

Tags: css

The title might not make a lot of sense so here is an image

[image]

Basically, I have a list of rounded elements inside a container. (left)

What I would like to achieve is to separate those rounded elements in 2 container while keeping the same design (right)

I'm not sure if that's possible... Any help would be appreciated

Here is a jsfiddle with the basic template : https://jsfiddle.net/786yvmah/3/

```
<div>
  <div class="container1">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
    <div>D</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <div>E</div>
    <div>F</div>
    <div>G</div>
    <div>H</div>
    <div>I</div>
    <div>J</div>
    <div>K</div>
    <div>L</div>
    <div>M</div>
    <div>N</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For example "E" / "F" / "G" should be right after the "D".

"H" / "I" / "J" / "K" should be right under "A" / "B" / "C" / "D"

"L" / "M" / "N" right after "K".

Comment: Try to add more explanation to your question it still not making sense to me be a bit clearer about your problem that what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `float: left` on `.container1`, so that contents of `.container2` will just flow around it. On a side note, you might want to  consider floating all your nested `<div>` so that you don't have an arbitrary whitespace between each of your circles:

```css
div > .container1 div,
div > .container2 div {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.container1 {
  float: left;

  /* Just to show where container1 is */
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container1">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
    <div>D</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <div>E</div>
    <div>F</div>
    <div>G</div>
    <div>H</div>
    <div>I</div>
    <div>J</div>
    <div>K</div>
    <div>L</div>
    <div>M</div>
    <div>N</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

p/s: Do note that if you're using CSS `float`, [remember to clear the float after that](https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/).

Answer (score 0):

I would give the main container a class and a display: flex to it like such.

```
.main
{
 display: flex;
}
```

I think this is what you want to achieve, this way you don't need to use floats.

Comment: But `display: flex` will not allow contents of container2 to flow around container1, unless you change the markup so that container2 is nested inside container1.